# Javascript mouseout event not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to stop the flagwave on mouseout but its not working. Once i mouseover it works but once i mouseout the mouseover action is looping its not stopping. Can i know whats the mistake i have done.

This is my js code:

```
    elem.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut , false);

function mouseOut(event) {
    var mouseX,
        mouseY;
    event.preventDefault();  // stops browser to do what it normally does
    // determine where mouse is
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY;
    // do something useful, e.g. change the flag to waving when mouse is over flag
    clearBangladesh();  
}

function clearBangladesh(){
    canvas.clearRect(0,0,300, 150);
    drawBangladesh();

}
```

THis is the code for the animation:

```
function waveFlag( canvas, wavelength, amplitude, period, shading, squeeze ){
if (!squeeze)    squeeze    = 0;
if (!shading)    shading    = 100;
if (!period)     period     = 200;
if (!amplitude)  amplitude  = 10;
if (!wavelength) wavelength = canvas.width/10;

var fps = 30;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var   w = canvas.width, h = canvas.height;
var  od = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;
// var ct = 0, st=new Date;
return setInterval(function(){
    var id = ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
    var  d = id.data;
    var now = (new Date)/period;
    for (var y=0;y<h;++y){
        var lastO=0,shade=0;
        var sq = (y-h/2)*squeeze;
        for (var x=0;x<w;++x){
            var px  = (y*w + x)*4;
            var pct = x/w;
            var o   = Math.sin(x/wavelength-now)*amplitude*pct;
            var y2  = y + (o+sq*pct)<<0;
            var opx = (y2*w + x)*4;
            shade = (o-lastO)*shading;
            d[px  ] = od[opx  ]+shade;
            d[px+1] = od[opx+1]+shade;
            d[px+2] = od[opx+2]+shade;
            d[px+3] = od[opx+3];
            lastO = o;
        }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(id,0,0);       
},1000/fps);
}
```

This is the mouseover function:

```
function mouseMove(event) {
var elem = document.getElementById('bangladesh-canvas');
var mouseX,
    mouseY;
event.preventDefault();  // stops browser to do what it normally does
// determine where mouse is
mouseX = event.pageX;
mouseY = event.pageY;
// do something useful, e.g. change the flag to waving when mouse is over flag
waveFlag( elem, 50, 5, 200, 250, -0.1 );

}
```

Is this the rightway to stop an event on mouse out? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean, you only want to prevent default usage, AFAIK, it is!

Comment: @nnnnnn i have added the animation code do take a look

Comment: I am sorry @nnnnnn this is my frist time writing java code. Can u explain to me more in detail

Comment: @nnnnnn i have added the mousover handler code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `waveFlag()` animation function works by calling `setInterval()`, which queues up some code to be run at regular intervals *forever* - unless you cancel it or navigate away from the page. So how to cancel it? It returns an id. You need to call `clearInterval()` and pass that id, which means you need to actually store the id value in a variable as shown below.

Also, both your mouseover and mouseout handlers have a lot of unnecessary code that doesn't do anything: you create variables and assign values but never use those variables. And there is no need to call preventDefault() because neither event has default behaviour that needs cancelling. So, try something like this:

```
var intervalId;

function mouseMove(event) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('bangladesh-canvas');

  intervalId = waveFlag( elem, 50, 5, 200, 250, -0.1 );
}

function mouseOut(event) {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  clearBangladesh();  
}
```

Keep your existing calls to `elem.addEventListener()` as they are.

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't just copy/paste this code and forget about it: read my explanation carefully, and examine all the code to try to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` is the common way to stop an event's default behavior from occurring. Also, try `e.stopPropagation()`, in case your event is bubbling up anywhere else in your code. The final thing to attempt is returning `false` from the function.

However, you might need to show code related to drawBangladesh(), as that may be the cause of your continuous looping, and without it I can't say for certain that your issue is the event handler.

If you're not too keen on event handling, this MDN page may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/More_Event_Handlers#Prevent_Default_Action

Comment: What is the default behaviour on a mouseout event? What would cancelling the default mouseout behaviour do?

Comment: i have added the animation code do take a look. actually once mouseover the flag will be waved and after the mouseout the flag should stop waving

Comment: @nnnnnn there actually is no default action, which is why I wanted to see the drawBangladesh() code :)